# Existence of others homomorphisms in $(\ell_\infty)'$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\ell_\infty$ the space of bounded sequences in $\mathbb{C}$. Knowing that $\ell_\infty$ is a $C^*$-algebra with coordinate-to-coordinate multiplication, show that exist a homomorphism $\tau:\ell_\infty\to\mathbb{C}$ such that is different of
$$
\delta_k:(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in\ell_\infty\mapsto x_k\in\mathbb{C}.
$$
The trip is check that $\delta_k$ is a isolated point, for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. In fact, how $\Omega(\ell_\infty)=\{\tau\in(\ell_\infty)':\tau$ is a homormorphism$\}$ is compact, once that $1=(1,1,\ldots)\in\ell_\infty$, then showing that $\delta_k$ is isolated implies that the sequence $(\delta_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ must have a accumulation point $\tau\in\Omega(\ell_\infty)$ such that $\tau\not\in(\delta_k)_{k=1}^\infty$, once that $\delta_k$ is isolated point.

Now, how I can show that $\delta_k$ is isolated point? $\Omega(\ell_\infty)$ is endowed with weak*-topology of $(\ell_\infty)'$. Me too don't know who's $(\ell_\infty)'$, it's $\ell_1$ (If is necessary to answer this question)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that $(\ell_\infty)'=\ell_1$. In fact, the homomorphisms coming  from $\ell_1$ are precisely the $\delta_k$.

To see that $\delta_k$ is isolated, you want to construct a weak$^*$-neighbourhood that contains $\delta_k$ and none of the other $\delta_n$. The obvious choice is to take $e_k\in\ell_\infty$ (the sequence with $1$ in the $k^{\rm th}$ coordinate and zero elsewhere) and use the neighbourhood
$$
V=\{x\in(\ell_\infty)':\ |x(e_k)-\delta_k(e_k)|<1\}.
$$